Comparing documents between two indices in OpenSearch
I have an old Java service that inserts data to Opensearch.
And a new Java service, that uses different mechanism to insert the data.
I want to make sure that I don’t have any gaps, and the new data is equal to the old data.
I was wondering if there is a way to query Opensearch (about multiple documents), and get the results only of such comparison (I have thousands of documents to compare).
